# How to add OS and simulator versions of static libraries into xcode 4

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, xcode4

I have come across an issue in my iphone app. I have the separate static library files for OS and simulator with the same names in my iPad app. I am able to run my app by adding OS and simulator library files separately.
Now I want to add both the static library files(have same names) at a time to the project folder, and compiler should recognise the appropriate OS or simulator files at compile time. How to do this?
I tried adding both the libraries at a time, it throws error.
So how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

From your two static libraries, you can build a universal static library using `lipo`.

Try this:

```
lipo -create myLibForSimulator.a myLibForDevice.a -output myUniversalLib.a
```

you should replace the `myLib...` placeholders with the paths to your actual libraries.

Comment: The name of the two files are same and newly built file also should be same for my app to run.. So if I use "lipo -create xyz.a xyz.a -output xyz.a".. wil it work?

Comment: yes, it will work... names are not important... but directories shall be different: `lipo -create path1/xyz.a path2/xyz.a -output path3/xyz.a`